# How can solve this sparqal

Tags: sparql

Write SPARQL query on the given data to get the list of the items in decreasing order of their
price value. Data:

@prefix : @prefix ns:
http://example.org/items/ http://example.org/ns#
:Apple ns: price 60
:Cherry ns:price 68
:Banana ns: price 36
:Milk ns: price 32

Answer this question with sparqal

Comment: did you try anything or is it really a plain request to solve your university assignment? If you did try something, please show it here and explain what did not work and why you're stuck. Otherwise, feel free to ask a service ChatGPT if you think this is the way to solve tasks in the future

Comment: as a hint, use a single triple pattern that matches the `ns:price` triples and the `ORDER BY` clause on the variable which you assigned the price to

Answer (score 0):

Using `ORDER BY` will order your result.

First, I would format your data a little better. This is turtle which looks like what you might be going for:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/items/> .
@prefix ns: <http://example.org/ns#> .

:Apple ns:price 60 .
:Cherry ns:price 68 .
:Banana ns:price 36 .
:Milk ns:price 32 .
```

The query for order is then pretty simple:

```
SELECT ?fruit ?price
WHERE
{ 
   ?fruit ?p ?price . 
}
ORDER BY DESC(?price)
```